# Conditional Formatting - Range error

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using the new Google Spreadsheet application.  Here is my data...

- Cell **B3 = 60**
- Cell B5 = 47
- Cell **B6 = 52**
- Cell B7 = 75.1
- Cell B8 = 68.4
- Cell B9 = 56

I setup this conditional formatting rule...

[image: screenshot]

For some reason that I do not understand, cell B6 turns red.  All the other cells are formatting the way I expect them to be.  When I change the "Range" in the conditional formatting rule to only "B6", it does not turn the cell red.  Am I misunderstanding the "Range" field?  Is this a defect or by design?

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I don't think you can use the `=sum` with `Greater than` - it needs to be a constant number (e.g. `60`). Try replacing `Greater than` with `Custom formula is`, and experiment with that. I haven't done much with the new Google Spreadsheets myself, so take it for what it's worth. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545961/google-spreadsheet-conditional-formatting-based-on-another-cell-value).

Comment: It should work, at least it does for me. I don't see the point in using `=SUM` on only one cell, though.
@VidarS.Ramdal `=SUM` does work with `Greater than`.

Comment: Can't reproduce your findings either. Can you share the doc with us?

Comment: @Punchlinern - It worked for you?  Are you using the new Google Sheets?  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/2TNrpc9xExY%5B1-25-false%5D

Comment: @Kirkland - I could have sworn it did, but it doesn't any more. Yes, I'm using the new Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: I have added a link to the Sheet (above).  I am testing, so you will see things change.

Comment: @Kirkland Why not in edit modus?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Its simple data.  Just replicate it.  Otherwise there will be multiple people changing things simultaneously and we wont be able to tell who did what and whats working.

Comment: I will make a new sheet, that's  working in the cloud.....

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra What did you write in the condition-textbox? If you look at [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZXMyx-nYxVSWzW2TOCcgaW4TEAePbeol5VSTp7GxdFQ/edit?usp=sharing) you can see (and edit) the problem. Look at the `D`-column. (The `B`-column is the working example in my answer.

Comment: @Kirkland - Did you see that I edited my answer, and removed `SUM` from it? I noticed that you use it in your example, it really isn't necessary to summarize the content of one cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually figured out a more direct way than the answer I originally selected as the correct answer.  `Conditional formatting` can use `Greater than` with a formula.  I was just using the wrong formula...

This is wrong... `Greater than` `=sum(B3)`

This is right...  `Greater than` `=$B$3`

Using the `$` to separate the column and row selector stops it from being dynamic.  Thus, `B3` will not become `B4`, `B5`, `B6`, etc, as the formula gets applied to each row.  It will always point to the value of `B3`, even if `B3` is itself based on a formula (aka: not static).

Answer (score 3):

Something seems to be off with the conditional formatting. One solution, anyway, as Vidar suggested, is to use `Custom formula is` instead of `Greater than` in the dropdown.
Use the formula `=B5>$B$3` with your range.